# The method 'validate' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

The Method `validate` is calling null

How can I fix it?

**Here is my code**

```
  saveUserInfoToFireStore() async {
    final GoogleSignInAccount gCurrentUser = gSignIn.currentUser;
    DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
        await userRefrence.document(gCurrentUser.id).get();
    if (!documentSnapshot.exists) {
      final username = await Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CreateAccountPage()));}
```

CreateAccountPage.dart

```
class _CreateAccountPageState extends State<CreateAccountPage> {
  final _scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String username;

  submitUsername() {
    final form = _formKey.currentState;
    if (form.validate()) {
      form.save();
      SnackBar snackBar = SnackBar(
        content: Text("Welcome" + username),
      );
      _scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackBar);
      Timer(Duration(seconds: 4), () {
        Navigator.pop(context, username);
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext parentContext) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      appBar:
          header(context, strTitle: "Settings", disappearedBackButton: true),
      body: ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 26.0),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Set up  a Username",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(17.0),
                  child: Container(
                    child: Form(
                      key: _formKey,
                      autovalidate: true,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        validator: (val) {
                          if (val.trim().length < 5 || val.isEmpty) {
                            return "user name is very Short";
                          } else if (val.trim().length < 10 || val.isEmpty) {
                            return "user name is very long";
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }
                        },
                        onSaved: (val) => username = val,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                          labelText: "Username",
                          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          hintText: "must be atleast 5 charecters",
                          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: submitUsername(),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 55.0,
                    width: 360.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.lightGreen,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Proceed",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with your `onTap` function.

> `submitUsername`  inside `onPressed` is a function reference, which means it is not executed immediately. It is executed after the user clicks on the `Button`

While,

> `submitUsername()` is a function call and it is executed immediately.

---

1. You should use `submitUsername` and not `submitUsername()`.

```dart
           GestureDetector(
                  onTap: submitUsername, //new line
                  child: Container(
                    height: 55.0,
                    width: 360.0,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.lightGreen,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "Proceed",
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 16.0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
               ),
```

**OR**

2. Call the `submitUsername` function inside an anonymous function that will act as a callback.

```dart
        GestureDetector(
                onTap: (){
                  submitUsername();
                },
                child: Container(
                  height: 55.0,
                  width: 360.0,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.lightGreen,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text(
                      "Proceed",
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 16.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```